# PayFlow Pro Test Declining

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I'm trying to set up a new testing account and I've gone through all the steps to do so, but all my test transactions keep declining and I'm not sure why.

This code processes live transactions in a live environment just fine, but this isn't working.

Here's my sample transmission (sensitive information redacted)

```
PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=[REDACTED]&USER=[REDACTED]&PWD=[REDACTED]&TENDER=C
&COMMENT1=00018165-0000&CUSTREF=00018165-0000&CUSTCODE=KEN&FIRSTNAME=
&LASTNAME=&ACCT=4242424242424242&EXPDATE=1218&ZIP=08052&CVV2=654
&STREET=123 ANYWHERE AVE&STATE=NJ&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=5.75
```

The response I get is this:

```
RESULT=12
PNREF=A10AA734F4BE
RESPMSG=Desclined
PREFPSMSG=Review: More than one rule was triggered
```

I have a feeling that I missed something in the account setup, but I don't know what.

BTW: I get the same result if I try to use the Virtual terminal on PayPal's website.

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 1):

I think you enabled Fraud Protection service and some filters are enabled which is declining your transaction.

With your payflow account go to manager.paypal.com then go to 'Service Settings' then 'Fraud Protection' and then check the enabled filters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed your instructions and I tried to disable all the fraud filters (this is a test account after all).  It's still declining with response code 12.  The triggered filters is says are "Price Ceiling" and "Item Ceiling". I modified the fraud trigger to allow up to 999999.99 but it still triggers...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the PayPal documentation :

Why did I get result code 12?

https://www.paypal.com/mk/smarthelp/article/why-did-i-get-result-code-12-ts1234

> **Pointing to test server**
>
> The test servers generate certain results for testing purposes, ***including a credit card being declined***. You can generate specific result codes by adding $1000 to that result code. For example, for result 13 (Referral), submit the amount $1013. If the amount is in the range $1000 to $1999.99 but doesn't correspond to a supported result code, a result 12 (Decline) is returned instead. Any amount of $2000.00 or more also generates a result code 12 (Decline). Live servers don't have this limitation and can process transactions of up to $99999.99.

To give an example of the above mentioned. We will use the curl command from the link below :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_payflow/#make-your-first-call

```
curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com \
-s \
--insecure \
-d PARTNER=PayPal \
-d PWD=MyPassword \
-d VENDOR=MyMerchantID \
-d USER=MyMerchantID \
-d TENDER=C \
-d ACCT=5105105105105100 \
-d TRXTYPE=S \
-d EXPDATE=1221 \
-d AMT=1.00
```

Change the amount in the test data

```
'AMT': '1000' 
> RESULT=0&PNREF=A71AAB63B3EC&RESPMSG=Approved&AUTHCODE=382PNI&PREFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered&POSTFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered

'AMT': '1013'
> RESULT=13&PNREF=A71AAB63B4A8&RESPMSG=Referral&PREFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered
```

To test more results in the link below a list of error codes.

RESULT Values for Transaction Declines or Errors
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/result_values_for_transaction_declines_or_errors.htm

You should also take into account the observation below.

> **Newly activated account**
>
> If you've recently activated your account, wait at least one hour after activation to process any transactions. If the transaction is otherwise valid, wait one hour and retry the transaction.